# How to symbolize points using line symbols of varying rotation and width?

Tags: qgis

I've been along a stretch of coast and recorded the orientation and thickness and locations of several igneous intrusions. I've managed to set up a project in QGIS with a point for each intrusion, each point is represented by a line which is rotated so I have the position and orientation.

What I'm trying to do change the thickness of each line to the thickness I recorded and form a sort of pseudo-polygon rectangle (the length of lines is just an arbitrary value) but I think my problem is I'm using rotated points represented by a line symbol :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a simple marker, give the **Ellipse marker** a try. You'll be especially interested in *Data defined setting* for symbol width and possibly rotation.

[image]